# IIS Express, ADFS & VPNs

Tags: c#, .net, vpn, iis-express

I am doing some work for a client and their applications are authenticated using ADFS.

I have a VPN into their network and can access their live running apps, servers etc all okay.

However when I try to run their code from Visual Studio, it runs as my local account (my machine name\login name) and then none of the authentication layers in the application work.

So is there a way to get Visual Studio\IIS Express (or IIS) to run as my VPN user

I have tried this

*runas /netonly /user:[domain][userid] devenv.exe*

and oddly that seems to work for passing through my VPN identity to SQL Server okay

however if I debug and run this command, it shows my local identity

*System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()*

Comment: So, what's the actual issue here? What behind this *none of the authentication layers in the application work* ? What kind of auth (active, passive) the app uses and what mode ADFS is configured for (integrated or forms)?

Comment: That's how `/netonly` works.  It doesn't change your local identity.  It only uses the provided credentials for NTLM authentication on the network.  And unless your computer is joined to their domain, you can't log on as a domain identity.

Comment: @WiktorZychla The problem is it uses some custom build assemblies (that I do not have access to) that use my identity to figure out what roles I have.  I was hoping there was some way I could run Visual Studio - or set up IIS so that it could see my VPN credential

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft  So is there anyway to force VS or IIS to run under my VPN credentials?